# Как сделать галлерею изображений как masonry, только горизонтальную и без js?

Tags: css

Совсем замучился с математикой, уже начинаю просто гадать. ( Нужно сделать галерею, типа masonry или justifeid, только без js, и горизонтальную.

Можно calc, можно flex, можно custom-properties, нельзя grid.

Вот что получилось (на качество кода не обращайте внимание, главное чтобы заработало, потом причешем):

```css
.pic-flex {
  --var-m: 8;
  display: flex;
}

.pic-flex div {
  --var-r: calc(1vw * var(--var-a) / 150);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  padding-left: calc(var(--var-w) / var(--var-h) * var(--var-r));
  height: var(--var-r);
}

.pic-flex div:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: calc(var(--var-m) * 1px);
  margin-bottom: calc(var(--var-m) * 1px);
}
```

```html
<div class="pic-flex" style="--var-a: calc(1200 + 800 + 800 + 2 * var(--var-m));">
  <div style="--var-w: 1200; --var-h: 768; background-image: url(//placehold.it/1200x768);"></div>
  <div style="--var-w: 800; --var-h: 600; background-image: url(//placehold.it/800x600);"></div>
  <div style="--var-w: 800; --var-h: 600; background-image: url(//placehold.it/800x600);"></div>
</div>
<div class="pic-flex" style="--var-a: calc(800 + 1360 + 800 + 2 * var(--var-m));">
  <div style="--var-w: 800; --var-h: 600; background-image: url(//placehold.it/800x600);"></div>
  <div style="--var-w: 1360; --var-h: 768; background-image: url(//placehold.it/1360x768);"></div>
  <div style="--var-w: 800; --var-h: 600;; background-image: url(//placehold.it/800x600);"></div>
</div>
<div class="pic-flex" style="--var-a: calc(1366 + 1920 + 1 * var(--var-m));">
  <div style="--var-w: 1366; --var-h: 776;; background-image: url(//placehold.it/1366x776);"></div>
  <div style="--var-w: 1920; --var-h: 768; background-image: url(//placehold.it/1920x768);"></div>
</div>
```

Нужно чтобы было так (аспект у картинок само собой должен быть нормальным):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Черт, кажется получилось! )))

**UPDATE: Неуниверсальное решение, с изображениями равной ширины, но разной высоты работает криво.**

```css
.pic-flex {
  --var-m: 8;
  display: flex;
}

.pic-flex div {
  --var-r: 18vw;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  height: var(--var-r);
  flex-basis: calc(100% / var(--var-a) * var(--var-w));
}

.pic-flex div:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: calc(var(--var-m) * 1px);
  margin-bottom: calc(var(--var-m) * 1px);
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .pic-flex {
    --var-m: 4;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pic-flex" style="--var-a: calc(1200 + 800 + 800);">
  <div style="--var-w: 1200; --var-h: 768; background-image: url(//placehold.it/1200x768);"></div>
  <div style="--var-w: 800; --var-h: 600; background-image: url(//placehold.it/800x600);"></div>
  <div style="--var-w: 800; --var-h: 600; background-image: url(//placehold.it/800x600);"></div>
</div>
<div class="pic-flex" style="--var-a: calc(800 + 1360 + 800);">
  <div style="--var-w: 800; --var-h: 600; background-image: url(//placehold.it/800x600);"></div>
  <div style="--var-w: 1360; --var-h: 768; background-image: url(//placehold.it/1360x768);"></div>
  <div style="--var-w: 800; --var-h: 600;; background-image: url(//placehold.it/800x600);"></div>
</div>
<div class="pic-flex" style="--var-a: calc(1366 + 1920);">
  <div style="--var-w: 1366; --var-h: 776;; background-image: url(//placehold.it/1366x776);"></div>
  <div style="--var-w: 1920; --var-h: 768; background-image: url(//placehold.it/1920x768);"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Придумал еще один вариант, у него и портретными и ландшафтными изображениями все нормально.

```css
.pic-flex {
  --var-m: 8;
  display: flex;
}

.pic-flex div {
  --var-r: 20vw;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  height: var(--var-r);
  flex: calc(var(--var-w) / var(--var-h)) 1 auto;
}

.pic-flex div:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: calc(var(--var-m) * 1px);
  margin-bottom: calc(var(--var-m) * 1px);
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .pic-flex {
    --var-m: 4;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pic-flex">
  <div style="--var-w: 1200; --var-h: 768; background-image: url(//placehold.it/1200x768);"></div>
  <div style="--var-w: 800; --var-h: 600; background-image: url(//placehold.it/800x600);"></div>
  <div style="--var-w: 800; --var-h: 600; background-image: url(//placehold.it/800x600);"></div>
</div>
<div class="pic-flex">
  <div style="--var-w: 775; --var-h: 477;; background-image: url(//placehold.it/775x477);"></div>
  <div style="--var-w: 775; --var-h: 1163; background-image: url(//placehold.it/775x1163);"></div>
  <div style="--var-w: 775; --var-h: 1089; background-image: url(//placehold.it/775x1089);"></div>
</div>
<div class="pic-flex">
  <div style="--var-w: 1366; --var-h: 776;; background-image: url(//placehold.it/1366x776);"></div>
  <div style="--var-w: 1920; --var-h: 768; background-image: url(//placehold.it/1920x768);"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо автору, очень полезная модель!
Небольшая ремарочка. Когда воспользовался методом из последнего поста, у меня содержащий галерею блок визуально отображался пустым. Выяснилось, что блоки с картинками-фонами имеют ширину 0. Причем я скопировал код в пустой html-файл, дабы убедиться, что это не какие-то сторонние стили. Эффект тот же самый. Не знаю, как у автора получилось отобразить галерею в примере корректно, у меня заработало, только когда прописал div'ам width:var(--var-r); (по аналогии с высотой).